# JqueryMobile Loader/spinner while loading another page

Tags: jquery-mobile, soap, wsdl, loader

Searched for almost 2 days and cant able to find a suitable answer.

I am developing a Jquery Mobile page.  Currently I have 2 JQuery Mobile pages.  When the page is launched it will show a button.  Hitting the button will send a SOAP request to the server to get a response.  After receiving the response the second page will be displayed.

The SOAP request might take a minimum of 3 to 5 seconds.  During that time I would like to show a loader/spinner on the centre of the page till I get the response from the server.  How to do that? Following is the code I use.

HTML File containing 2 pages

```
<form name="frm_login" action="" method="post">
  <div id='pg_login' data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="content">
      <input type="submit" name="btn_login_submit" id="btn_login_submit" value="Login" />
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div id='pg_menu' data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </div> 
  </div>
</form>
```

Javascript code as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var xmlRequest = getXmlRequest();
    loadingStart();
    $.soap({
      url: 'full wsdl url',
      method: 'getUserName',
      data: xmlRequest,
      success: function(xmlResponse) {
        loadingEnd();
        $.mobile.changePage('#pg_menu');
      },
      error: function(xmlResponse) {
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});

function loadingStart(){
  $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
    text: "loading",
    textVisible: true
  });
}

function loadingEnd(){
  $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
}
```

I also keep a 5 second sleep time in the WSDL function for testing purposes.

The loader is not displaying.  Please let me know what is going wrong here.

Regards
Malai

Comment: 1) `form` should be wrapped in `data-role=page` not the other way around. 2) dont use `.ready()` in jqm. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4a6SH/

Comment: Why we should not use .ready() inside JQM?

Comment: Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()

The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event. This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the jQuery SOAP plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/soap/)

After I change to native AJAX things started working fine with the below code.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
    text: "loading...",
    textonly: false,
    textVisible: true,
    theme: 'a',
    html: ""
  });
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $.mobile.loading('hide');
});
```